# Why Mapper Interface changed to Class in the new API?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

As i understood that in the new API : org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce , Mapper and Reducer are changed from Interface to Class.
Was there any limitation that in the new API they are changed from Interface to Classes? 
if yes, Can anyone explain with live example that where interface can't work?

Answer (score 0):

They have changed mapper from interface to class because if you are implementing an interface then there is a restriction that you have to implement all functions of that interface, otherwise it will throw error.

But if you are extending or inheriting a class then you don't need to be.

I hope everything is self explainable now.